# Doctrine MongoDb - ReferenceMany loading says Can't canonicalize query

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I followed this tutorial and everything works fine: http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/bidirectional-references.html

But I changed the location where the references get stored. In the example above the post holds one user. But I changed it, so the user will get an array of posts. Saving works fine.

But if I load a user and say `$user->getPosts()` I get zero results. If i look into mongodb, no references are saved. So I changed the annotation in `User` to `/** @ODM\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="BlogPost", cascade="all") */` (note the cascade="all" here has changed). Now references are saved to mongodb.

If I load the user again and say `$user->getPosts()` I get the following error message:

`Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'localhost:27017: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $in needs an array' in`

I debugged into `Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Persisters\DocumentPersister` in the method `loadReferenceManyCollectionOwningSide()` where the `in` operator gets build (line 697). Unfortunately as you can see in the screenshot, everything seems fine. The `in` operator has an array. So I can't imagine what is going wrong?
[image]

EDIT/Further information:
So I found out a little more. If I change both entities' mapping to `ReferenceMany` I can load `$post->getUsers()`, but not `$user->getPosts()`. Note, that the `User` entity is the owning side. But why???

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer your question but is some general debugging advice.

Doctrine is kind of a terrible in my experience (we had to remove it because it introduced way too much slowness and poor performing queries). However to diagnose this issue, I would imagine that you would need to enable general query logging to find the actual query sent or use wireshark or mongosniff to capture it.

Given the error, it could be any $in clause in the query not just the one you found. Also since it is entirely managed by Doctrine there is the possibility that it would override the $in clause you found at some later point if it is not generate another bad $in clause in the query.